# How to fix OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, django, pip, backend, fastapi

I tried installing Fastapi framework dependencies using the `pip install Fastapi[all]` command.
The packages were downloaded but during installation, I got this error.

```
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for python-multipart, since package 'wheel' is not installed.

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)

Installing collected packages: sniffio, idna, colorama, typing-extensions, h11, click, anyio, websockets, watchgod, uvicorn, urllib3, starlette, six, pyyaml, 
python-dotenv, pydantic, MarkupSafe, httptools, dnspython, charset-normalizer, certifi, ujson, requests, python-multipart, orjson, jinja2, itsdangerous, fastapi, email-validator

  WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'c:\\python39\\Scripts\\watchgod.exe' -> 'c:\\python39\\Scripts\\watchgod.exe.deleteme'

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python39\lib\site-packages)
```

**Python version**: Python 3.10.0
**pip version**: pip 21.3 from c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)

Comment: do you have wheel installed ? `pip install wheel`

Comment: tried installing wheel and i got the same error message. ``` 
Installing collected packages: wheel
  WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'c:\\python39\\Scripts\\wheel.exe' -> 'c:\\python39\\Scripts\\wheel.exe.deleteme'
 ```